# bash remove common lines from two files

Tags: text-processing, diff, comm

I have two files, (no blank lines/Spaces/Tabs)

#### */tmp/all*

```
aa  
bb  
cc  
hello  
SearchText.json  
xyz.txt
```

#### */tmp/required*

```
SearchText.json
```

---

and the end output I want is : (all uncommon lines from /tmp/all)

```
aa  
bb  
cc  
hello  
xyz.txt
```

I have tried below commands :-

`# comm -23 /tmp/required /tmp/all`

```
SearchText.json
```

`# comm -23 /tmp/all /tmp/required`

```
aa  
bb  
cc
hello  
SearchText.json  
xyz.txt
```

`# comm -13 /tmp/all /tmp/required`

```
SearchText.json
```

`# comm -13 /tmp/required /tmp/all`

```
aa  
bb  
cc  
hello  
SearchText.json  
xyz.txt
```

`# grep -vf /tmp/all /tmp/required`

`# grep -vf /tmp/required /tmp/all`

```
aa  
bb  
cc  
hello  
SearchText.json  
xyz.txt
```

`# comm -23 <(sort /tmp/all) <(sort /tmp/required)`

```
aa  
bb  
cc  
hello  
SearchText.json  
xyz.txt
```

Comment: while updating the formatting on your post, I noticed some trailing spaces on some of the lines; are there trailing spaces on any lines of your actual files?

Comment: Take a look at the diff command.

Comment: @JeffSchaller in actual file there are no trailing spaces or tabs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to `comm`, consider [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
grep -vxFf /tmp/required /tmp/all
```

This asks for the lines in `/tmp/all` that do not (`-v`) exist in the file (`-f`) `/tmp/required`. To avoid interpreting any line in `/tmp/all` as a regular expression, I added the "fixed strings" `-F` flag. In addition, we want to force the entire line in `/tmp/all` to match the one(s) from `/tmp/required`, so we use the `-x` option.

This method does not require sorted input.

I suspect that your `comm -23 <(sort ...) <(sort ...)` command would work, if the "SearchText.json" line matched *exactly* in both files (same amount of trailing spaces, if any).